# ¿Cómo incrementar el valor de los números de una lista sin crear una nueva en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucles, matemáticas

quiero saber como hacer para poder incrementar el valor de los números de una lista, sin tener que crear una nueva lista con los valores valores incrementados.

La idea sería que los números originales sean sobreescritos por el nuevo valor.

Por ejemplo, si tengo esta lista, y quiero incrementar el valor en 5:

```
nums = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

El output debería ser:

```
nums = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
```

Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Hay diversas formas de hacerlo, pero debes mostrar el camino que has tomado para poder ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: `for i in range(len(nums)): nums[i] += 5`

Comment: Gracias Candid Moe

Comment: @CandidMoe por favor, pon eso como respuesta (con una breve descripción de qué es y cómo funciona). Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nums = [100, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Cada elemento de la lista `nums` es accesible usando subíndices. El primer elemento de la lista es `nums[0]` y vale 100, en este caso. El segundo elemento es `nums[1]` y así sucesivamente.

Si quieres modificar un elemento de la lista, basta con asignarle un nuevo valor. Por ejemplo:

```
nums[0] = 5
```

Cambia el primer elemento de la lista, que ahora queda así:

```
nums = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Luego, si quiero sumarle 5 a cada elemento lo puedo hacer en un ciclo `for` que recorra todos los indices desde cero hasta el último.

En cada ciclo tomamos el elemento `nums[i]` y le sumamos 5. El resultado queda almacenado en el mismo elemento `nums[i]`.

```
for i in range(len(nums)):
    nums[i] += 5
```

produce:

```
[10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizarlo mediante una list comprehensions. Si tienes esta lista de números

```
nums = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Lo que debes hacer es a la lista guardada en `nums` es cambiarla mediante una list comprehensions que sea guardada en esa misma variable, y a esa list comprehensions colcarle que el valor a guardar debe ser incrementado.
En tu caso debes incrementar el valor en 5 entonces el código quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
nums = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
valor_incremental = 5
nums = [numero+valor_incremental for numero in nums]
```

En la parte de `numero+valor_incremental` se le suma al elemento iterado de `nums` el valor incremental que es 5, despues `for numero in nums` es la parte donde se intera la lista `nums` obteniendo cada elemento de la lista.

Si imprimimos la lista `nums` después de modificarla nos dará el siguiente resultado

```
[10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
```

De esta forma se ahorran líneas de códigos, por cierto la variable de `valor_incremental` esta de mas, la puedes borrar y en la misma list comprehensions colocar `numero+5`. Coloque esa variable para que sea mas entendible.